# Comma instead of semicolon, Why does this statement not give syntax error in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int a  = 10;
    printf("\n a = %d", a),int(3);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine in C++ (http://ideone.com/RSWrxf) but the same `printf` line does not work in C. Why does it work in `C++`? I'm confused about comma being allowed between two statements and C/C++ compilation difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`int(3)` is not valid syntax in C. You could write it like this though:

```
printf("\n a = %d", a),(int)3;
```

or even just:

```
printf("\n a = %d", a),3;
```

and this would compile in both C and C++.

Note that the comma between the `printf` and the redundant expression following it is just the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The results of both the printf call and the following expression are discarded.

Comment: What about it ? It's just the usual comma operator found in C, C++ and related languages.

Comment: Probably worth noting that this is nothing to do with the comma. You would have exactly the same problem if you separated the two expressions with a semicolon.

Comment: I mean how does it accept statements with comma between them, rather than semicolons?

Comment: Answer updated - you should probably update your question also to make it clear that you're specifically confused by the comma.

Comment: @PaulR In fairness, his confusion was thinking the comma was the reason it didn't compile in C. He was unaware of his lack of knowledge about the comma operator, and that the int(3) was the real reason.

Comment: @IanGoldby: you're probably right - if he had *included the actual error message with his question* then it would probably have avoided some unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `int(3)` works in C++ is because it's a [functional cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). This isn't supported in C, which is why it fails there.

As Paul R already explained, the statement works in C++ since the `,` (comma operator) simply ignores the return value of the expression to the left of the `,` (but does execute it).

So in C++, the line `printf("\n a = %d", a),int(3);` is evaluated like this:

- `printf("\n a = %d", a)` is executed. It's result is discarded.
- The number 3 is cast to `int`, but since it isn't assigned to a variable this statement has no effect and is discarded.